# Автоматическое форматирование объекта (Python)

Tags: python, объекты

Разработанная мною python-функция возвращает большой объект в одну строку (примерно такой, как в примере, только в десятки раз больше)

```
{'a':{'b':1,'c':2,'d':{'e':{'f':3}}}}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы возвращаемый объект автоматически приходил в отформатированном виде, примерно вот таким:

```
{
  'a': {
    'b': 1,
    'c': 2,
    'd': {
      'e': {
        'f': 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[json.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=dumps#json.dumps)

```
import json

obj = {'a':{'b':1,'c':2,'d':{'e':{'f':3}}}}

print( json.dumps(obj, indent = 2) )
```

А если словарь изначально создается в виде строки,

```
obj = """{'a':{'b':1,'c':2,'d':{'e':{'f':3}}}}"""

print( json.dumps(eval(obj), indent = 2) )
```